# How to know if app is removed from background in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How to know if app is removed from background in SwiftUI? Is there any method just like Swift and how to use it?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate

Answer (score 0):

I'd research the [`Scene`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scene) protocol.

I quote...

> The Scene protocol provides scene modifiers, defined as protocol
> methods with default implementations, that you use to configure a
> scene. For example, you can use the onChange(of:perform:) modifier to
> trigger an action when a value changes. The following code empties a
> cache when all of the scenes in the window group have moved to the
> background:

and to be clear this is the example provided by Apple...

```
struct MyScene: Scene {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    @StateObject private var cache = DataCache()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MyRootView()
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newScenePhase in
            if newScenePhase == .background {
                cache.empty()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I place this in my App file, like in the following example (with Core Data implementation):

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {

    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared
    
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    
    var body: some Scene {
        
        WindowGroup {
            
            NavigationView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { _ in
            
            persistenceController.save()
        }
    }
}
```